# Python printing array

Tags: python, arrays, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract weather information and display it on my website. I have managed to extract weather for 1 day. Now I am trying for the entire week. I was thinking the best way to do this is with an array. I have an array seven_days[] which is assigned temperatures from the days of the week.

```
def weatherWeek_():
page = requests.get("https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/weather/forecast/u2fkbqee7#?date=2018-02-23")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
seven_days = [1,2,3]
today = soup.find (id="tabDay")
seven_days[0] = today.find(class_ = "dayTemp").get_text()

today = soup.find (id="tabDay1")
seven_days[1] = today.find(class_ = "dayTemp").get_text()

today = soup.find (id="tabDay2")
seven_days[2] = today.find(class_ = "dayTemp").get_text()

return seven_days
```

I connceted to the website and in cmd assigned values to the array when I print it

```
print(seven_day)
```

I retreive the correct information however I have a mistake in displaying the information back on my webpage. The assigned values(temperatues) are correct howeve when I want to diplay it on my page it doesn't work. Here is the entire code:

```
from datetime import date
from flask import Flask, Response, redirect, render_template, url_for, redirect, request
import sqlite3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
DB_FILE = 'mydb'

@app.route('/')
def main():
daytemp = weather_()
seven_days = weatherWeek_()
return         render_template('PragueMainPage.html',daytemp=daytemp,seven_days=seven_days)
#----------------------------------------------------------

@app.route('/history')
def history():
return render_template('History.html')
#----------------------------------------------------------

@app.route('/contacts', methods=['POST','GET'])
def view4():
connection = sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM contacts")
rv = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
return render_template("Contacts.html",entries=rv)
#----------------------------------------------------------

def weather_():
page = requests.get ("https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/weather/forecast/u2fkbqee7#?date=2018-02-23")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
today = soup.find (id="dayNav")
daytemp = today.find(class_ = "dayTemp").get_text()
return daytemp

def weatherWeek_():
page = requests.get ("https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/weather/forecast/u2fkbqee7#?date=2018-02-23")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
seven_days = [1,2,3]
today = soup.find (id="tabDay")
seven_days[0] = today.find(class_ = "dayTemp").get_text()

today = soup.find (id="tabDay1")
seven_days[1] = today.find(class_ = "dayTemp").get_text()

today = soup.find (id="tabDay2")
seven_days[2] = today.find(class_ = "dayTemp").get_text()

return seven_days


if  __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/ingridpython.css') }}"/>
        <title> Prague - Main Page</title>
    </head>

    <body> 
        <div class ="flex-container">
           <div class ="navigation">
               <ul>
                   <li><a href ='/'>Main Page </a></li>
                   <li><a href ='history'>History </a></li>
                   <li><a href ='gallery'>Gallery </a></li>  
                   <li><a href ='guestbook'>Guestbook </a></li>
                   <li><a href ='comments'>Comments </a></li>
                   <li><a href ='registration'>Registration </a></li>
                   <li><a href ='contacts'>Contacts </a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>  
         </div>

         <div id ="container1">
            <div id ="containerWeather">Today's temperature:{{daytemp}}</div>
            <h1>Prague Week's temperature:{{seven_days}}</h1>
        <p1> Prague is the capital and largest city in the Czech Republic</p1>

      </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any error message? What is shown on the webpage, when you render it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seven_days` is a `list` you are passing in `HTML`.

Use `for` loop to display all items in list:

```
<div id ="container1">
        <div id ="containerWeather">Today's temperature:{{daytemp}}</div>
        {% for temp in seven_days %}
            <li>{{ temp }}</li> <!--substitute li with any tag--> 
        {% end for %}
    <p1> Prague is the capital and largest city in the Czech Republic</p1>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I get the issue now. I will play around with the for loop to get it working.